# Use mask to hide stroke, without hiding the layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, cs6

How can I mask a stroke effect itself? E.g., suppose I have this shape:

[image]

So I want to do something like this without modifying its pixels:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is...

- Duplicate the pixel layer
- Add the stroke via Layer Styles
- Ensure **Layer Mask Hides Effects** is **checked** in the `Blending Options` window
- Add a layer mask
- set the `Fill Opacity` to 0%.

[image]

You can then paint on the mask all you want, or alter the stroke style options, without altering the underlying pixel layer.

[image]

(I changed the color of the duplicate merely to show that the fill pixels aren't actually seen in the document)

Comment: This needs to be re-done everytime the shape is modified, e.g., if you just resize the shape you need to duplicate it again, otherwise my stroke is -> [dat](https://i.imgur.com/Kjlp0QX.png).

Comment: I found it very helpful though. Photoshop misses flexible lines and curves :/